# C# Listview sort successful but trying to move scrollbar to top...how?

Tags: c#, sorting, listview, scrollbar

Sorted the listview and tried to "refresh" it by selecting the first element and thus putting the scroll position at the top but it's not quite working. Here's my code:

```
if(lv_sets.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
{
    lv_sets.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false;
}

if (columnSorter.SortingOrder == SortOrder.Ascending) 
{
    columnSorter.SortingOrder = SortOrder.Descending;
    lv_sets.Sort();
}
else
{
    columnSorter.SortingOrder = SortOrder.Ascending;
    lv_sets.Sort();
}

lv_sets.Items[0].Selected = true; //This selects the item but it doesn't move the scrollbar to the top. Why?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
lv_sets.Items[0].EnsureVisible()
```